# Why this set is of the second category?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, baire-category

I'm watching [Baire space on en.wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space), and find this conclusion.

Here is an example of a set of second category in $\mathbb R$ with Lebesgue measure zero.

$$\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(r_n - \frac1{2^{n+m}}, r_n + \frac1{2^{n+m}}\right)$$

where $\{r_n\}$ is a sequence that enumerates the rational numbers.
my question is :

Why this set is of the second category?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: @AlexR thanks,I'll improve my level of formulations-editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every set $G_m=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(r_n - \frac1{2^{n+m}}, r_n + \frac1{2^{n+m}}\right)$ is a dense open set because is union of open sets and contains the rational numbers. So it's complement is nowhere dense, and hence $B=\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty G_m'$ is of first category which $G_m'$ is the complement of $G_m$.
Now observe that $A=B'=\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(r_n - \frac1{2^{n+m}}, r_n + \frac1{2^{n+m}}\right)$ must be of second category.

*Note*. We used De Morgan's laws in the last line.